# Vidéo not displayed on Mozilla and IE7, but works on chrome

Tags: html, flash, cross-browser

I have in my page a movie that i call with :

```
<object width="500" height="405"><param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/_wKFwii6LF0&amp;hl=fr_FR&amp;fs=1&amp;color1=0x2b405b&amp;color2=0x6b8ab6&amp;border=1" name="movie"></object>
```

In Chrome it is displayd, in IE and Mozilla, there is an error...How can i debug...
(For info, this is the link to the real page :
http://www.syca-distribution.fr/portiques.aspx
At the bottom: 
Chrome : plays the video
IE: shows a placeholder with error
Mozilla: shows nothing...

any idea ?
Thanks
John

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either a) add an EMBED tag or b) add the required extra values to the markup - see [Flash OBJECT and EMBED tag attributes](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html)  and [Macromedia Flash OBJECT and EMBED tag syntax](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/415/tn_4150.html)

Comment: Thank you. What is surprising is that the code i use is taked from YouTube...I'll try